# Proving $\lambda(ab) = \mathrm{lcm}\{\lambda(a),\lambda(b)\}$ where $\lambda(.)$ is Carmichael's Function

Tags: number-theory

In proving :

> if $a$ and $b$ are coprime integers then $\lambda(ab) = \mathrm{lcm}\{\lambda(a),\lambda(b)\}$

where $\lambda(.)$ is Carmichael's Function

where does $a$ and $b$ are coprime is used?

One proof is [here](http://www.yimin-ge.com/doc/carmichael.pdf)  (lemma 6)

Comment: @BalarkaSen I corrected it. Thanks.

Comment: This is an immediate consequence of the recursive definition (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function#Composition)

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Would you mind explaining the statement?
Actually, I want to know why if that condition is removed then the property doesn't hold?

Comment: @MahdiKhosravi, $\lambda(8)=2\iff a^2\equiv1\pmod{2^3}$ if $(a,2)=1$ and $\lambda(6)=2$ But, $\lambda(8\cdot6)=?$ try with $a=5$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is used implicitly in the paragraph preceding Lemma 6, namely

$$\rm\lambda_{ab}\mid n\!\!\overset{\ Lem3}\iff\! x^{n}\!\equiv 1\,\ (mod\ ab)\ \color{#c00}\Leftarrow\!\!\!\!\!\overset{CRT\ \ \ \ \  }\Rightarrow\!\!  \begin{array}{}x^{n}\!\equiv 1\,\ (mod\ a)\\ \rm x^{n}\!\equiv 1\,\ (mod\ b)\end{array}\!\!\overset{\ Lem3}\iff\! \lambda_a,\lambda_b\mid n\!\iff\! lcm(\lambda_a,\lambda_b)\mid n $$

$(\color{#c00}\Leftarrow)$ needs $\rm\,(a,b)= 1,\,$ i.e. $\rm\,a,b\mid c\!\iff\! {\rm lcm}(a,b)\mid c,\, $ and $\rm\,{\rm lcm}(a,b) = ab\iff (a,b)=1.$

Comment: Thanks. But why does it need to be correct in the other direction?

Comment: @Mahdi I edited the answer to make it clearer how the other direction is used, i.e. the deduction is a series of $\iff$ equivalences. The linked proof is not as clear as it could be.

Comment: Why do the right-arrows aren't enough to prove the statement?

Comment: For $n = \lambda_{ab}$ the $(\Rightarrow)$ gives ${\rm lcm}(\lambda_a,\lambda_b)\mid \lambda_{ab}.$ For $\,n={\rm lcm}(\lambda_a,\lambda_b)\,$ the $(\Leftarrow)$ gives $\,\lambda_{ab}\mid {\rm lcm}(\lambda_a,\lambda_b).\,$ So they are equal, dividing each other.